# kafka on kubernetes does not receive messages from external producer

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

Hello (I use the google translator).
I have the following problem, I have a Kafka service in kubernetes, everything is managed by rancher and the deployment of kafka is done through the catalogs that rancher allows, (I attach an image of the service)

[image: 1]

Everything works correctly within kubernetes, but now I need a producer external to kubernetes connects to Kafka and sends messages so that they are received internally in kubernetes.
I have not been able to accomplish this task and I have already tried another kafka deployment following this guide:

https://www.weave.works/blog/kafka-on-kubernetes-and-deploying-best-practice
[1]

But I can't understand both in the version of rancher catalogs and not in the version installed through YAML files, where and what should I configure to have a producer outside of kubernetes, I also tried to set the service as NodePort but this didn't work, any help you are welcome and thank you.

Comment: You'll need to show your actual service definitions and producer code for any help diagnosing your issue

Answer (score 0):

NodePort is one option. A LoadBalancer or Ingress is another.

Rather than use Rancher catalogs, I'd recommend that you read through the Strimzi operator documentation, where it covers all options for external client communication